# Send Matlab data to Raspberry USB port

Tags: usb, data-transfer, matlab

I would like to connect to the USB port of the Raspberry Pi with a device (for example: a USB sound card), and send data from Matlab to the Raspberry Pi's USB port in which the USB device is connected.

I have realized that there is a Simulink block to communicate in Matlab with the audio port on the Raspberry. Instead I would try to communicate with a device connected to Raspberry USB port.

Do you think it is possible to do that? I don't see any Matlab/Simulink block that would permit me to do that.